# How to dynamically create texture from set of widgets in Kivy?

Tags: python, widget, textures, kivy, python-3.4

I have a square layout with many sets of widgets. Set of widget presents empty widget with colorful background (I draw it with primitives) and one or more labels over it, so set is 2 or more widget. I animate each set independently (like 2048-game, if you know). For now, I have to clear canvas and redraw my background for each frame. It's OK if there are 4×4 sets, but if there are 7×7 or more, it's pretty laggy. So it seems it would be much better to create just one texture from every set and animate only it (as I don't change its content until I destroy it). How can I do that and is it possible at all? And is it smth better than my idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand a lot of your question, but what you really want to do is store your graphics instructions and change their positions, rather than deleting them and recreating them every frame. This will be very significantly faster, and is the intended way to update graphics.

For instance:

```
with self.canvas:
    rect = Rectangle(pos=(0, 0), size=(10, 10))

rect.pos = (50, 50)
```

This changes the pos of the rect very efficiently, rather than deleting it.

Comment: It seems it less laggy now, but still. I meant, can I make only one texture from many widget, kind of common sum of textures. It seems it called "blit" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Sort of, but this way of thinking is not generally appropriate to kivy, it's not a pixel pushing (and texture blitting) toolkit, but has an opengl oriented api. You will get better performance by trying to work naturally with this - there is no reason for your stuff to be laggy that cannot be solved by improving your graphics code without messing with blitting.